# Best way to manage local changes to Ansible Galaxy role

Tags: ansible, devops, ansible-galaxy

I am fairly new to Ansible. I am using a couple of Ansible roles that need some tweaking of specific tasks to work on CentOS 7. What is the best workflow to handle local changes to Ansible-Galaxy roles?

Here are the options I am considering:

1. Fork the role and make change. Downside is that I would lose the ability to grab dependencies by running `Ansible-Galaxy install -r requirements.txt`
2. File an issue with the developer on github. Downside is they may never accept my change or may take several days/weeks.
3. Make changes locally. Downside is I wont be able to update roles from galaxy without losing my local changes.

Comment: For the 1st option, why would you lose the ability to grab the dependencies?

Comment: After reading the [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/galaxy.html#advanced-control-over-role-requirements-files) for ansible-galaxy command I didn't realize it could be pointed directly at github for dependencies. Problem solved thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After reading the [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/galaxy.html#advanced-control-over-role-requirements-files) for the `ansible-galaxy` command I realized I could be pointed directly at my github fork and not affect the ability to grab dependencies using `Ansible-Galaxy install -r requirements.txt`.

## Example: Adding a github repo to requirements.yml:

`# from GitHub
src: https://github.com/bennojoy/nginx`

Comment: Note: even if doing this, make sure to track the upstream PR and switch back to the upstream role—that is, if it's something minor that has a good chance of getting merged. Otherwise you're now the maintainer of everything in that role, but only for your one use case :)